# Animation in tag "Summary"

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How can I make an animation when the "+" is flipped by 45 degrees with details open and the "close" symbol is obtained using only html and css

Html:

```
<details>
    <summary>Sites</summary>
    <p>Google</p>
    <p>YouTube</p>
</details>
```

CSS:

```
summary:before{
 content:"+";
}
```

Comment: what you tried ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example because without seeing what code is involved any answer will be just a guess. In particular we need to know what element(s) you want to animate. Thanks.

Comment: @dippas, I have completed the question

Comment: @AHaworth, I have completed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may override defaut style of `<summary>` and use a transition.

possible example

```css
summary {
  list-style: none;/* removes the default arrow */
}
summary:before {
  content: "\25b2";
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  transition: 0.25s;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
[open] summary:before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>hello</summary>
  <p>the world!</p>
</details>
```